# Calling return methods from within a different method's parameters

Tags: java, variables, methods, standards

Does anyone know what the official word on this is?  Here is an example:

```
public void makeStuff(int total) {
    //method logic
```

Now lets stay I call this method like this:

```
new Thing().makeStuff(new OtherClass().getTotal); 
//OtherClass holds the int total that is returned
```

Is this bad programming style to do this?  And lets just assume the standard way is not an option. (i.e. new Thing().makeStuff(7));

Thank you all in advance.
Matt

Comment: Seems perfectly fine, except that the readability of the code is impacted a little.

Comment: I can't see there is any problem...

Answer (score 3):

Well if you're not going to be keeping any reference to the class then why not use static methods instead?

```
public static void makeStuff(int total) {
//method logic
```

and in your other class the total will always be the same - as it has no chance of being set, unless getTotal was supposed to be a method call (getTotal()), in which case that could also be a static call ie

```
Thing.makeStuff(OtherClass.getTotal());
```

Comment: I agree...however, I have to keep it as an instance variable for reasons that I won't trouble everyone with.  Thank you, though, for your input.  It seems like this idea is of initializing parameters in this way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create an object like this to get one value, and I wouldn't call a field `getTotal`

You might do

```
new Thing().makeStuff(new OtherClass().total);
```

OR

```
new Thing().makeStuff(new OtherClass().getTotal());
```

OR

```
new Thing().makeStuff(OtherClass.getTotal());
```